# Java Scanner - asks for user input before print() statement

Tags: java, printing, java.util.scanner

I'm following along with my university course, writing the code word for word. I'm having a problem where the `print()` statements will be skipped and the user has to enter 2 different inputs until it outputs the print messages (see output below). The reason why I'm not using the `println()` is because it is required that the keyboard input is on the same line as the print statement. When I use the `println()` statement it works but outputs the keyboard input under the `println()` output.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class temperature {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter today's temperature: ");
    int today = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter tomorrow's temperature: ");
    int tomorrow = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Today is " + today + " degrees.);
    System.out.println("Tomorrow is " + tomorrow + " degrees.");
  }
}
```

**The output for this is:**

```
12
13
Enter today's temperature: Enter tomorrow's temperature: Today is 12 degrees.
Tomorrow is 13 degrees.
```

**The desired output:**

```
Enter today's temperature:12
Enter tomorrow's temperature:13
Today is 12 degrees.
Tomorrow is 13 degrees.
```

Is there any way to fix this without changing the code too much?

Comment: Try calling `System.out.flush();` after each `print`. Your console might be buffering.

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing that problem at all. Other than missing a quotation mark in line 13, the code compiles and executes exactly as you would expect. I tried it on an online Java compiler and via terminal and it works fine. What tool (IDE) are you using to write, compile and execute your code?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I'm using NetBeans as my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with NetBeans, for some reason only does that in Maven Projects. I created a new Ant Project and I didn't have that issue.